# Save object name into a instance variable during GSON Deserialization

Tags: json, object, gson, json-deserialization

**Suppose I have a json file like this:**

```
{
  "ObjectName1": {
    "enabled": true,
    "SSOIDS": []
  },
  "ObjectName2": {
    "enabled": true,
    "SSOIDS": []
  },
  "ObjectName3": {
    "enabled": true,
    "SSOIDS": []
  },
  "ObjectName4": {
    "enabled": true,
    "IDs": []
  }
}
```

**I want to derserialize the data and store the "ObjectNameX" into a field, objectName, of my Java object e.g:**

```
public class Feature implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String objectName;

private Boolean enabled;

private List<String> IDs;

private boolean checkLastTwoChars; //sometimes my json objects might have this
                                    //element.However in this example it doesn't
//Getters and Setters left out for brevity
```

**I have read a bit on creating a custom deserializer [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)
  and have created the below class:**

```
public class FeatureDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Feature>   {
    public Feature deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Feature ft = new Feature();
    if(!json.isJsonNull()){
        ft.setFeatureName(json.getAsJsonObject().getAsString());
        //json.getAsJsonObject().getAsString()--> `{"enabled":true,"SSOIDS":[],"checkLastTwoChars":false}
    }
    return ft;
   }

}
```

but the json parameter in the deserializer doesn't have access to the objectNameX during runtime i.e only the key value pairs of the objet fields are available.
I know GSON is deserializing the correct values and has access to the a objectNameX from eclipse debugger.

**Here's how I am calling the fromJson():**

```
// just the part I think is relevant 
Map<String, Feature> featureCache = new HashMap<String, Feature>();
for(File file : files){
            try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while(br.ready()){
                        sb.append(br.readLine());
                    }
                    br.close();
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().
                            registerTypeAdapter(Feature.class, new FeatureDeserializer()).create();
                    featureCache = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), new TypeToken<SortedMap<String, Feature>>(){}.getType()); // features in a specific file
```

**Is there a standard way for saving each objectNamex in each unique object that I deserialize??**

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the problem of saving each objectNamex in each unique object that I deserialize however I am still unsure if this is a best or even common practice.

**I realized that:**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().
                        registerTypeAdapter(Feature.class, new FeatureDeserializer()).create();
                featureCache = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), new TypeToken<SortedMap<String, Feature>>(){}.getType()); // features in a specific file
```

is actually creating a map with the objectNamex as the key to each unique Feature object therefore

**I created a helper function:**

```
private void fillInFeatureNames(Map<String, Feature> featureCache){
        for (String featName: featureCache.keySet()){
            featureCache.get(featName).setFeatureName(featName);
        }
    }
```

that cycles through each key in the map and sets each unique feature object featureName field to the keyname. This is a valid work around but I still wanted to know if there was a preferred practice in this effort.

Comment: I've just asked a similar question that will likely be solved by the same answer, so keep an eye on that if you'd like. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806233/using-gson-to-deserialize-to-a-map-but-modify-the-map-key